# How Can I represent my data in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write my first Python program - one that will parse a source file (javascript) and create some type of cross reference report.

I want to save the following information for all vars and functions:

- Variable Name
- Type (var or function)
- Line Declared
- Scope - could incorporate this into the Name field - e.g. Main::myvar
- Initial Value
- Line(s) Modified
- Line(s) Referenced

There is no guarantee that each variable has only been declared once. (I do have some cleaning up to do.)

Can anyone please suggest how I can save the details as I traverse the input file?

My OS is Win 10 and I'm using 3.6

Comment: What have you tried so far? We won't write code for you; we're here to solve your code problems and answer your questions.

Comment: You maybe unaware that you almost wrote "I am going to write a compiler as my first Python program", (and I wouldn't recommend that, because it is a complex and challenging task - that is why Nilo answer talks about "a long journey"). As for the specific "how can I save the details", trees are usually used for that  because you can represent nested structures with them and they are efficient for search/traversal (you put the read tokens in the tree and then analyze it as you wish)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are starting a long journey. If you want to parse a source code file, you will first have to tokenize it. Here is a function that tokenizes a simple arithmetic expression, to get you started.

```
OPERATORS = '+', '-', '*', '/'

def tokenize(expression):
    def state_none(c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token = c
            self.state = state_number
        elif c in OPERATORS:
            self.token = 'operator', c
            self.token_ready = True

    def state_number(c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token += c
        else:
            self.char_consumed = False
            self.token = 'number', self.token
            self.token_ready = True
            self.state = state_none

    def interpret_character(c):
        self.token_ready = False
        self.char_consumed = True
        self.state(c)

    class self:
        token_ready = False
        token = None
        char_consumed = True
        state = state_none

    for c in expression:
        self.char_consumed = False
        while not self.char_consumed:
            interpret_character(c)
            if self.token_ready:
                yield self.token
    if self.state == state_number:
        yield 'number', self.token

def main():
    for x in tokenize('15+ 2 * 378 / 5'):
        print(x)

    # ('number', '15')
    # ('operator', '+')
    # ('number', '2')
    # ('operator', '*')
    # ('number', '378')
    # ('operator', '/')
    # ('number', '5')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But really, get your hands dirty: write some code that opens the file, iterates over the characters, and does something with them (group them in tokens).

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies - maybe in V2 I'll incorporate the code that nilo provided.

Comment: I got to the point where I had stripped out comments and passed any executable lines to a def to "process".<br>
e.g. var SymTF_P2 = Symbol + "," + TF_P2; ==> {'varName': 'main::SymTF_P2', 'type': 'variable', 'defLine': [112]}
My initial thought was to store in dict but soon realised that this approach was not going to work because the next entry for each key would clobber  the existing value.